# iOS7 Startup screen (splash screen) leave a space on the bottom

Tags: cordova, ios7, splash-screen, iphone-5

I have a problem occurring when starting up my iOS7 Phonegap app with iPhone 4 inch, the startup screen goes up and leave an empty space on the bottom (and we can see the view behind) :

http://screencloud.net/v/5gAO
(I have hidden most of the splashcreen, but you can see the space on the bottom)

I only hide the screenshot once my app is loaded (AutoHideScreenshot = FALSE), maybe I am doing something wrong when the app is sarting ?

Everything looks correctly configured in XCode:
[image: screenshot XCode]

Any idea? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just found the solution here: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-4391
If you can't update cordova, you can apply the fix. Open CDVSplashScreen.m and replace the line:

```
imgBounds.origin.y -= statusFrame.size.height;
```

by this line:

```
    if (!(IsAtLeastiOSVersion(@"7.0"))) {
        imgBounds.origin.y -= statusFrame.size.height;
    }
```

It's because in iOS7, the status bar is integrated in the view (it doesn't take place)

Answer (score 2):

In addition to

```
<key>UIStatusBarHidden</key>
<true/>
<key>UIStatusBarHidden~ipad</key>
```

You need to also add another key in your .plist so your cordova app is not impacted by the new status bar mode

```
<key>UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance</key>
<false/>
```

Cheers
D

Comment: OK, it works, now I don't have an empty space during launch, but I just realize that now, the status bar is always hidden (it's not what I want). Sorry, I remove the "answered mark", still looking for a solution